# Transfer String via TCP/IP to multiple computers

Tags: c#, string, tcp, kinect, tcplistener

This code currently takes kinect Body data and writes it in an Excel Worksheet. I have another code that is able to create a TCP/IP connection between two computers. How would I best combine these two ideas?

I require this Joint String Data to be sent over the network and collected by another server computer, in real-time, not in an excel file. Do you have any suggestions ?

In other words, I have some Server code, but i want the server to listen for the Kinect String Data that the client code (Another computer) is generating and currently is writing it to a local excel file.

**Client Side**

```
...
  _recordBody = !_recordBody;
                if (_recordBody == false)
                {
                    recordButton.Content = "Record";
                    return;
                }
                recordButton.Content = "Stop Recording";
                currentTrackingID = 0;
                // create a csv file and write file header
                string currPath = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
                string folder = "recordings";
                string recordPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(currPath, folder);
                if (!Directory.Exists(recordPath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(recordPath);
                }
                timeRecordingStarted = DateTime.Now;
                string filename = timeRecordingStarted.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss");
                filename = filename + ".csv";
                filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(recordPath, filename);
                string[] writtentext = {"time," + "headX," + 
                                        "headY," +
                                        "headZ," +
                                        "headS," +
                                        "neckX," + 
                                        "neckY," +
                                        "neckZ," +
                                        "neckS," +
                                        "spineShoulderX," + 
                                        "spineShoulderY," +
                                        "spineShoulderZ," +
                                        ...
                                        "handLeftY," +
                                        "handLeftZ," +
                                        "handLeftS," +
                                        "handTipRightX," + 
                                        "handTipRightY," +
                                        "handTipRightZ," +
                                        "handTipRightS," +
                                        "handTipLeftX," + 
                                        "handTipLeftY," +
                                        "handTipLeftZ," +
                                        "handTipLeftS"
                                       };
                File.WriteAllLines(filePath, writtentext);
         ...
```

**Server Code**

```
    static TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(10);
    static void Listeners()
    {

        Socket socketForClient = tcpListener.AcceptSocket();
        if (socketForClient.Connected)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Client:"+socketForClient.RemoteEndPoint+" now connected to server.");
            NetworkStream networkStream = new NetworkStream(socketForClient);
            System.IO.StreamWriter streamWriter =
            new System.IO.StreamWriter(networkStream);
            System.IO.StreamReader streamReader =
            new System.IO.StreamReader(networkStream);


            {
                string theString = streamReader.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Message recieved by client:" + theString);
                if (theString == "exit")
                    break;
            }
            streamReader.Close();
            networkStream.Close();
            streamWriter.Close();
            //}

        }
        socketForClient.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit from server program");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        //TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(10);
        tcpListener.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("************This is Server program************");
        Console.WriteLine("How many clients are going to connect to this server?:");
        int numberOfClientsYouNeedToConnect =int.Parse( Console.ReadLine());
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfClientsYouNeedToConnect; i++)
        {
            Thread newThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Listeners));
            newThread.Start();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: On client side you can use TcpClient. But i'd suggest you to consider using WCF. This will spare you from dealing with connection and data serialization.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! We have looked into and looked for a client code that uses WCF, however we were unable to find any sources online for our purpose. Do you know of any sources we could look at and how to implement them?

Comment: Check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/getting-started-tutorial). And also, you can adapt this wcf chat sample to your situation [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/607801/SimpleplusChatplusprogramplusinplusC)